# What is the maximum size limit for a touchpad?

Tags: touchpad

This is more of a hardware question, but i wanted to know: what's the maximum feasible size that a touchpad can be made? I am wondering because someone remarked to me the other day that the surface on an iPod Touch is basically a touchpad, so how big can they be?

Comment: FYI, a touchpad uses the same technology as a capacitive touch screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, technically, there CAN be a limit - Being as big as to consume too much electric energy that the computer's power supply can't handle. This would-be size is too big to be functional and practical for a human user, however.

So, practically - You can have it as big as you need.

Take a look at: [Wikipedia's entry about touchpads.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchpad)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't [Microsoft Surface](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/)  a huge touchpad, too?

Comment: Nope, it uses IR cameras to see where your fingers are you the surface.

Answer (score 1):

My [FingerWorks](http://www.fingerworks.com/) keyboard has no keys -- instead, the entire surface of the keyboard is a giant touch surface. ([More info here.](http://fingerfans.dreamhosters.com/bin/view/Main/FingerWorks))

[image]

Comment: Looks very cool. Too bad Apple shut them down.

Comment: Yep, too bad and no reason for it either. They could have kept selling the wares to us uber-geeks while using the tech in the iPhones and mAcbooks, but the old business had to die. Pity.